# Search hard drive for a string and return all result with certain directories ignored

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that do the following:
1) Search all the directory under drives (C: D: E: F: G: ) for a "keyword"
2) Return result that the path does NOT contain the word "Users", "Desktop" and "Recyele" (in other word, ignore results under these directories).  Here's the code:

```
@echo off & setLocal EnableDELAYedeXpansion
for %%d in (c d e f g) do if exist %%d: (
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/b/s %%d:\abc.txt 2^>nul ^| findstr /V /C:"Recycle" /C:"Desktop" /C:"Users"') do (
set var1=!var1! %%a,
)
echo %var1%
)
endlocal
```

the code works fine except I want to return ALL result instead of just the first found.
I have searched stackoverflow and there was question doing ignore result, combine result and findstr but not a combination of all.  Thanks in advance.

@Edit - Desktop search engine suggested but extra software isn't an option (Thanks Ark)

Comment: Why don't you use a desktop search engine for this?

Comment: @arkascha Hi, it is a part of my code where I will be doing the same for numerous VMs.  It will be too time consuming to do manually

Comment: Why manually? You are _currently_ doing it manually, whilst a search engine is an existing and working application you can just use. You can configure such engine to scan all drives used inside those VMs on the host system.

Comment: I don't have access to the host system but only the VMs.  Is the search you mentioned can be done on just any station that has remote desktop access to the VMs?  By the way, is it possible to have the search automated?

Comment: Well obviously the decision which search engine to use depends on what desktop environment we are talking about. Most of todays desktop environments already bring such an engine. Those engines typically work in background, so kind of automatically. How you can query results from the index they build again depends on the engine you use...

Comment: It seams you are not familiar with the term "desktop search engine". Take a look here, it is quite a common thing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_search

Comment: Thanks Arkascha for the alternative, but the VMs are all in different environment, plus it is only part of my code where other task are involved (i.e. setting registry, gathering OS info, etc) hence coding it instead of a separate procedure will be essential.

Comment: You can query the search index from within your scripts, once it has been generated by the search engines. This decouples the scanning of those millions of files from your actual code.

Comment: Thanks, the search engines are useful, but also it seems like you will need to install extra software on your desktop, which cannot be done in my environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will loop through each drive, search for a file, and exclude certain results.  Do not call the `exit` command because that will stop the script.  Also recommend piping directly into `findstr` to speed it up.  Use the `/V` option for findstr.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%D in (c d e f g) do if exist %%D: (
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir/b/s %%D:\myfile.exe 2^>nul ^| findstr /V /C:"Recycle" /C:"Desktop" /C:"Users"') do (
        echo %1, %%A,
    )
    echo %1,,
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks David, sorry for being such a greedy, is it possible to append the result to a variable?  I tried set Var=%var% %%%A% but it didn't work

Comment: @Alex So instead of the `echo %1, %%A` you want to append the value to a variable?  You will need to use the delayed expansion syntax (exclamation marks).  `set "var=!var!, %%A"`  Also, are you wanting to expand the value of `%%A`?  If so, you will need to use the delayed expansion syntax there as well. `!%%A!`

Comment: Thanks David!  I will have a try and let you know what I come up with.  Thanks for your patient.

Comment: Hi David, I fails to make use of the delayed expansion.  I updated my code in the question to have !var1! included but it returns nothing.  I was trying to append all the search result into var1 and at the end, echo the list I found.  Thanks again

Comment: @Alex  Change the echo line to also use exclamation marks for the variable expansion.  `echo !var1!`

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is because you've added `EXIT` into the loops. Take it out.

```
@echo off 
setLocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%d in (c d e f g) do (
  if exist %%d: (
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir/b/s %%d:\myfile.exe 2^>nul') do (
      Echo.%%a | findstr /C:"Recycle" /C:"Desktop" /C:"Users">nul || echo %1, %%a,
    )
  )
)
echo %1,,
```

Comment: Thanks Matt your answer works well too but David answered earlier (2 min) so I will go with his answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, David answered 2 minutes **After** me. You know this because his un-edited answer is above mine. The latest post appears first. But his is the better answer because it's more concise code. :)